# Excel sort numbers smallest to largest with cells that contain multiple numbers with "/" or "," between numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a column of numbers

[image: Original List]

I want to sort the list smallest to largest numbers, but any number with a "/" or "," will be put at the end.

[image: Sorted List]

How can I sort from smallest to largest where the numbers with "/" or "," will also be sorted in the list instead of being sorted at the end?

I will have to sort the numbers from smallest to largest and expand the selection to the column on the left which contains company names (not pictured).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:A14,
     SORTBY(_Data,--TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(_Data,",","/"),"/")))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function it helps in defining variables and hence reduces to use of repeated ranges/formulas.
- Using `SUBSTITUTE()` function substituting one of the delimiters, here I did the `comma` with the `slash` so that it becomes consistent.
- Using `TEXTSPLIT()` splitting the data with a delimiter slash `/`, so when using `TEXTSPLIT()` to split an array it will give the first split values as an array and converting the same into True numbers using `--` double unary.
- Now, basing the above within a `SORTBY()` function, taking `_Data` as **`array`** while sorting **`by the array`** returned using `TEXTSPLIT()` function in `A-Z` or `Smallest-Largest` that is in ascending order.

---

As per OP edit to the post, there should not be any problem with the following just need to add the `TAKE()` function:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:B14,
     SORTBY(_Data,--TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(_Data,,-1),",","/"),"/")))
```

---

Comment: You're the best!